# How to set key equivalent programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to set a key equivalent on a button. To set it in the Attributes Inspector in XCode does not work. I want to set 'fn + enter'. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Is the button a `NSButton`? Does the button have a `keyEquivalent` property? Is "does not work" "Xcode does not set it" or "It looks ok in Xcode but the key equivalent does not work"?

Comment: Yes, NSButton. No property. XCode does not set it. It sets enter, but not fn.

Comment: I could solve it partly. -(void)okKey:(NSNotification*)notification{ [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]; } sets the key equivalent 'return'. But how can I add 'fn'?

Comment: I don't know if you can add fn, see [keyEquivalentModifierMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton/1532670-keyequivalentmodifiermask).